# Full hydrate vs per field hydrate best practices

Tags: django, tastypie

I'm getting quite familiar with Django and Tastypie but I have a question about best practices. When I'm hydrating data coming from a POST, should I prefer to hydrate all fields directly in the hydrate function or it's recommended to hydrate each field separetely in the corresponding hydrate_field subfunction? In my case I have only 4 fields and to me it seems faster to simply define the hydrate function with 5 lines of code performing the complete transformation of the provided bundle.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hydrating all 4 fields in a single hydrate method is totally fine, just be careful not to hydrate data for read-only fields.

Comment: Thanks Sean! So I'd say that the ad hoc hydrate_field functions have to be used when there's a lot to do for a single field, and therefore we want to keep our code cleaner. Do you agree?

Comment: Yes, just for keeping the code cleaner.